# Stack Runnables in a queue with ThreadFactory

Tags: java, android

I have a method that takes 4 second to execute, if the user calls it again before it ended than it will refresh, I want to only start the new one after the last one has finished, putting them in a queue.

I've read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory%29), but I still don't know how to implement it, can someone provide an example please?

**Code**

my method:

```
    public void popClassAdded(int amount){

    classAddedText.setText(getString(R.string.you_earned) + amount + " ");
    setIn = new AnimatorSet();
    setIn.playTogether(
            Glider.glide(Skill.QuintEaseOut, 200, ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(classAddedLayout, "translationY", -50, 165))
    );
    setIn.setDuration(1200);
    classAddedLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    setIn.start();
    classAddedLayout.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
            set.playTogether(Glider.glide(Skill.CubicEaseInOut, 200, ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(classAddedLayout, "translationY", 165, -50)));
            set.setDuration(1200);
            set.start();
            set.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {                    }
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    classAddedLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {                  }
                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {                    }
            });
        }
    },2000);

    shopPrefs.edit().putInt("coins", amount + shopPrefs.getInt("coins", 0)).apply();

}
```

Calling it:

```
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //may get clicked more than once in an interval or 4 seconds
                ((Activity_Main)getActivity()).popClassAdded(100);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What have you done so far?  What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: The method is getting called independently if it's already running or not. I know I have to use a ThreadFactory but I don't know exactly how to do so.

Comment: How about showing some code so we can get a better idea of what you're doing?